# Silverlight - How to get Webresponse string from WebClient.UploadStringAsync

Tags: silverlight, webclient

```
    public void Register(string email, string name, string hash)
    {
        string registerData = "{\"email\":\"" + email + "\",\"name\":\"" + name + "\",\"hash\":\"" + hash + "\"}";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(HandleRegisterAsyncResult);
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(registerUrl), registerData);
    }

    void HandleRegisterAsyncResult(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
```

}

I'm basically trying to call a webservice with a https:// post command that takes a data string.  It works well, except when I get an error I can't seem to find the actual WebResponse content. If I cast the e.Error that was returned to a WebException there's a class called Response that's a BrowserHttpWebResponse but the ContentLength is 0 (eventhough I can see the content lenght is not 0 in fiddler)

Is there a way to get the response content with this method?  And if not is there another way to do a Post command that does allow me to get the response content?